# Cordova FCM notifcations not received on IOS, While app is in background

Tags: ios, firebase, cordova, cordova-plugin-fcm

I'm using these plugin on cordova@8.1.2:

```
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-device" spec="^1.1.6" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="^1.3.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-wkwebview-engine" spec="^1.1.4" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" spec="https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-firebase" 
    spec="git+https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebase.git#GH-1057-April-05-android-build-issue" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" spec="^2.0.1" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-androidx" spec="^1.0.2" />
    <plugin name="cordova-plugin-androidx-adapter" spec="^1.0.2" />
```

I've tried many different guides, I'm using legacy Build, set the p8 key on firebase for APN and in Android FCM messaging works smoothie. On IoS I can receive it only when the app is in the foreground.

I think the problem is related to "Disconnected from FCM" string. I obtain this log whenever I close or I switch my App.

Comment: Were you able to resolve it?

Comment: Sorry for late answer.. Yes, I started to use `corodova-plugin-firebasex` as DaveAlden said.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using my old fork of `cordova-plugin-firebase` (https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebase.git#GH-1057-April-05-android-build-issue) which is only a partial fix for that plugin's multiple unresolved issues.

Please try using my fork of that plugin - [cordova-plugin-firebasex](https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-plugin-firebasex) - which resolves numerous issues with FCM notifications and adds new functionality.

Note: the latest version - `cordova-plugin-firebasex@5.0.0` - contains breaking changes such that the API is no longer the same as `cordova-plugin-firebase`. If you decide to migrate, please read the documentation carefully.